# Is my code HTML and CSS proper, and how do I add a hover effect to just the text in the nav bar?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm just getting into web design, and I'm wondering if my nav bar code in HTML and CSS is written properly or not. It works, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to write the code, or if I missed something that really should be in the code. Also, if anyone knows how to add a hover effect to just the text in the nav bar without changing it background color that would be much appreciated (similar to Apple's nav bar).

HTML and CSS:

```css
#mainheader {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    text-aling: center;
}
#mainheader #mh-content ul {
    background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
}
.mh-button-link {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font: 16px Verdana, Georgia, serif;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainheader" class="mainheader">
   <div id="mh-content">
      <ul>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="homepage.html">Home</a>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Forum</a>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">New</a>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Popular</a>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Login</a>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Contact</a>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">FAQ</a>
         <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Search</a>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: No, You are missing `:li>` inside `<ul>`

Comment: The `hover` pseudoselector is what you should use to add a hover effect: `#mainheader li:hover { ... }`.

Comment: Please note that I just autoformatted your HTML/CSS to make your post easier to read - just pointing it out because that's part of "writing code properly", which you were asking about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks mostly fine to me. As others have suggested, you're missing `<li></li>` inside of your `<ul>`. Also, there is a typo in your CSS: `text-aling` should be `text-align`.

---

To add a hover effect, add a new color to the link's `hover` pseudoclass:

```
.mh-button-link:hover {
    color: gray;
}
```

If you want it to transition, add transitions to your link:

```
.mh-button-link{
 ...
 -webkit-transition: color 250ms ease;
 transition: color 250ms ease;
}
```

Here is a live, correct example:

```css
#mainheader {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#mainheader #mh-content ul {
    background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
}
.mh-button-link {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font: 16px Verdana, Georgia, serif;
    -webkit-transition: color 250ms ease;
    transition: color 250ms ease;
}
.mh-button-link:hover {
    color: gray;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainheader" class="mainheader">
   <div id="mh-content">
      <ul>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Forum</a></li>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">New</a></li>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Popular</a></li>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Login</a></li>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">FAQ</a></li>
         <li><a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/na0ke180/

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `<li>` tags inside your `<ul>`. Anyway, the rest looks good.
For references regarding html, you can visit many pages like eg. http://www.w3schools.com/

And for your text hover effect, add the following.

```
.mh-button-link:hover{
   opacity: 0.6;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
           transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
 }
```

**Apple like hover effect**

See this fiddle, for your apple-style hover effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/z9xmgoza/1/

Answer (score 0):

### See thi [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/0gm38s7u/embedded/result/)

**HTML**

```
<nav id="mainheader" class="mainheader">
    <div id="mh-content">
        <ul>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="homepage.html">Home</a>    
            </li>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Forum</a>    
            </li>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">New</a>    
            </li>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Popular</a>    
            </li>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Login</a>    
            </li>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Contact</a>    
            </li>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">FAQ</a>    
            </li>
            <li> <a class=mh-button-link href="FAQpage.html">Search</a>    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also, add these below given CSS to your Stylesheet

**CSS**

```
#mainheader #mh-content ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
#mainheader #mh-content ul li:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

For the `hover` effect, there is a pseudo class called `:hover` in CSS.